# How can I block date in html5 calendar

Tags: javascript, php

everyone, I'm creating a calendar with html5 that can block specific dates automatically, that information is in PHP variables, I have arrays for days, month, year to be blocked in the calendar, how can I achieve this? I just need an idea how can I do, this must be done in javascript, right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calendar</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['reservation']) && !empty($_POST['reservation'])) {
            $startDate = $_POST['start'];
            $endDate = $_POST['end'];
        }
    ?>

    <form class="" action="" method="post">
        <label for="start">Date init</label>
        <input type="date" id="start" name="start" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" max="2021-08-10">

        <label for="end">Date end</label>
        <input type="date" id="end" name="end" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" max="2021-08-10">
        <input type="submit" name="reservation" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It depends on how you want to implement your requirements.  JavaScript is one option.  You could also use an HTML form and submit to PHP.

Comment: Is for a little reservation system in another script I got variables of dates that need to block for evade overbooking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML input[type=date] does not support any limitation beyond setting a min and a max date [1]. Anything beyond these basics will require custom logic. If this is a reservation system, it might be an option to replicate the date selectors from e.g. airlines or hotels. This could be done mostly on the server with only a thin layer of JS on the client to handle the user selection.

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: this could be done in php ?? I have all the dates to be blocked in another script. Yes this is a litle reservation system

Comment: e.g. like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673936/php-calendar-start-calendar-from-monday

Comment: or do you recommend store dates in mysql to replicate??

Comment: Well, that depends on what you want to do. But should be independent from how you present the data to the user.